# Floating divs not properly clearing both

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am attempting to have a basic page lay out, however my second div is tucking it's self under neath what will eventually become a jQuery slider. Could some one help me figure out why it isn't doing what it needs to.

Heres my Css::

```
body{
background-image:url('background-body.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
}

#mainWrap{
    clear:both;
    top:20%;
width:600px;
height:500px;
background-color:#c0c0c0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
position:relative;
box-shadow:10px 10px 10px #000000;
}

.floater{
position:absolute;
margin-bottom:25px;
width:100%;
height:300px;
top:0;
z-index:1;
border:solid 1px;
background-color:white;
box-shadow:0 10px 10px #000000;
display:block;
clear:both;


}

#footer{
bottom:0;
position absolute;
width: 100%;
border:dashed 1px;
height: 60px;
background-color:white;
}

</style>
```

And the basic html I have so far.

```
</div>

<div id="nav">
</div>

<div id="mainWrap">

</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

edit:: http://jsfiddle.net/EnGKs/ js fiddle<-- as you can see the secondary div is under the top one, I need it to clear the top one so the entire div is viewable

Comment: what is wrong with what it looks like now?

Comment: Demonstrate it in a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `postition:absolute`, as this removes the element from the flow, therefore causing it to overlap.

```
.floater{
    position:absolute;
}
```

[**Working jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EnGKs/3/)

If you need absolute positioning for the slider, apply it to the children within it instead.